# How to update routes.rb (dynamic urls)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I have this code in my routes.rb

```
shops = Shop.all
shops.each do |shop|
match "/#{shop.url}" => 'shops#show', :id => shop.id
end
```

So url can be like http: //site/url & not like http: //site/shops/1

& It does work, but I have to restart server after adding a new shop.

Maybe, there is a way to do this stuff without restarting? Or, some other way around?

Thank you

Comment: What sorts of things are in `shop.url`?

Comment: string. For example -> http://site/mycoolshop. User is able to write any url for his shop.

Comment: So why not use a simple `/:url` route, index the `url`s, and then lookup the shop based on `:url`? You'd have to be careful about route order, conflicts between `:url` and other routes, and constraints on the route if you allow `.` of course.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I'm not very good at routes :) I'm sorry , can you give me an example :) How it should be written in routes.rb? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old rails cast, but you'll find elements of answer there

http://railscasts.com/episodes/63-model-name-in-url

As a general advise: you won't need do this kind of loop in your routes, study the tools made available by rails routing and use them

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: Cool :) Thank you.
It's working, how can I delete "shops" from url, right now it is http://site/shops/1-mycoolshop    Can it be like http://site/1-mycoolshop ?

Comment: Yes it can, I am not sure (because it depends on your routing configuration, nesting, etc...) but I would use something like this: `match '/:shop' => 'shop#show'` (and in your ShopController#shop you'll receive a value in params[:shop]). Just be sure to put this line at the very end of your routing block or it will match for any other URL. You should really study the rails guide I linked in my answer, you'll feel more comfortable with routes